# Uber OAuth Redirect URI error

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth, uber-api

I'm trying to develop a web application on Uber's API using javascript and node.js, and when trying to authenticate the user with OAuth 2.0, I'm getting the error

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

This occurs after this snippet of code, where I display the login page as specified by Uber:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
var loginURL = "https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/login";

  request(loginURL, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    }
  });
});
```

In my uber account, I have added all of the following to the Redirect URL section under authorization:

```
http://localhost
http://localhost:3000/login
https://localhost:3000
https://localhost:3000/login
```

One interesting thing is that I see this error in the console of the browser when the page loads, but then I also get a pop up error with the same message when I click "login with facebook" and the url of the popup error is under the facebook domain (https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?app_id=277064115737714&client_id=277064115737714&display=popup&domain=localhost&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FPqAPb......) Could it be something with the redirect uri that uber is sending to facebook?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to configure this in your Facebook app settings as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about the js code, but in my iOS app, the authorization redirect url can either be your app's domain or the link from your server side. And you need to register it on Uber's app dashboard of yours on `https://developer.uber.com`

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Just use [**Grant**](https://github.com/simov/grant) for authorization and you'll be fine. You are not supposed to render the authorization page by yourself - it doesn't work that way! This defies the purpose of the authorization_code flow. You have to redirect the user instead, but Grant will handle that for you, and it also plays well with any of the major web frameworks for NodeJS, like Express, Koa and Hapi.

Comment: @CBroe What do we need to configure in the Facebook app settings?

Comment: @BK: Platform, App Domains, Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: @simo, thanks, tried out Grant and got it to work smoothly!